# How to create a one way relationship?

Tags: entity-framework

Hi I'm currently learning entity framework and I'm a little bit confused about relationships. Given two Models:

```
public class Professor
{
    ...
    public List<Faculty> Faculties { get; set; }
}

public class Faculty 
{
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required,MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have table Faculties, that should only contain those attributes I listed. Like so

```
╔════╦══════════╗
║ Id ║ Name     ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║ 1  ║ Faculty1 ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║ 2  ║ Faculty2 ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║ 3  ║ Faculty3 ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║ 4  ║ Faculty4 ║
╚════╩══════════╝
```

But what I'm getting after migration is this.

```
╔════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ Id ║ Name     ║ ProfessorId ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ Faculty1 ║             ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2  ║ Faculty2 ║             ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 3  ║ Faculty3 ║             ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 4  ║ Faculty4 ║             ║
╚════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Entity Framework is adding a shadowforeignkey to the table. If I would leave it like this I would end up with duplicate Faculty entries like this

```
╔════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ Id ║ Name     ║ ProfessorId ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ Faculty1 ║ 1           ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2  ║ Faculty1 ║ 2           ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 3  ║ Faculty1 ║ 33          ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 4  ║ Faculty2 ║ 7           ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 5  ║ Faculty3 ║ 5           ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 6  ║ Faculty4 ║ 99          ║
╚════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

How do I want it to look? Professor entries should be able to reference 1 or more Faculty entries. But Faculty entries should not know about Professor entries. I don't want to have duplicate Facutly entries just because professors can reference the same faculty.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe my question is a bit dumb but I'm honstly confused...

Comment: You need many to many relationship, try Add a collection of professors on Faculty class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `public List<Faculty> Faculties { get; set; }` is making EntityFramework to think like you have a One-To-Many relation ships, which basically means in English that :

***One proffessor could be in several faculties but one faculty would could have one proffessor.***

Now you can think more than one way,

**If you have the idea that a professor can work only in one faculty, then your classes should be as follows :**

```
public class Professor
{
    ...
    public int FacultyId { get; set; }
    public Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
}

public class Faculty 
{
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required,MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Professor> Professors { get; set; }
}
```

and in your `DbContext` :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Faculty>().HasMany(i => i.Professors)
                              .WithOne(i => i.Faculty)
                              .HasForeignKey(i => i.FacultyId);
```

Now you will have `Faculties` Table contains only `ID` and `Name` fields, where `FacultyId` would be added to `Professors` table.

**But on the other hand If you have the idea that a professor can work on multiple Faculties and a faculty can have more than one professors, this is what we call a *`Many-To-Many`* relationship, and your structure should be as follows :**

```
public class Professor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<ProfessorFaculty> ProfessorFaculties { get; set; }
}

public class Faculty 
{
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required,MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ProfessorFaculty> ProfessorFaculties { get; set; }
}

public class ProfessorFaculty
{
     public int ProfessorId { get; set; }
     public Professor Professor { get; set; }
     
     public int FacultyId { get; set; }
     public Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
}
```

and in your `DbContext` :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProfessorFaculty>().HasKey(i => new { i.ProfessorId, i.FacultyId });
```

**Now, as you see we've added a new Table which represents the ManyToMany relationship and in our dbcontext we've set the primary keys of our new table.**

For example to ProfessorFaculty Table :

- Prof1 Faculty1
- Prof1 Faculty2
- Prof1 Faculty3
- Prof2 Faculty1
- Prof2 Faculty3

For adding a ProfessorFaculty:

```
public void AddProfessorToFaculty(int professorId, int facultyId)
{
   var professorFaculty = new ProfessorFaculty
   {
       ProfessorId = professorId,
       FacultyId  = facultyId 
   };
    
   _context.ProfessorFaculties.Add(professorFaculty);
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I needed your second example. Then how do I add a `Faculty` to the `Professor`? Do I need to add manually a `ProfessorFaculty-Object` to the `ProfessorFaculties`-list of the Professor with ProfessorId and FacutlyId added by myself or is there a better way?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer, for adding PorfessorFaculty entities, you can check it. :) This is the general way of doing this. Get the Id of the entity1, and get the id of the entity2, then create the manytomany entity and add it to your db.